# 403 on AWS S3 When File Extension is Caps, but Works Fine when Lowercase

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a public S3 bucket which holds a bunch of images.  When I viewed some images on the website I noticed that one of the images was getting a 403 error.  I went to my AWS console and clicked in the overview tab for the image, which showed the image correctly.  So I checked my original link against the link from S3 and the only difference was the link with the 403 had JPG vs jpg for the extension.

```
So 
https://s3.amazonaws.com/site-images/136_226/111111.JPG
vs
https://s3.amazonaws.com/site-images/136_226/111111.jpg
```

I would think that this would not be an issue, so if someone could shed a bit more light on why this would be an issue I would greatly appreciate it.

Wade

Answer (score 0):

S3 is case sensitive even if your local OS is not. Either the name matches exactly, character for character, or it won't be found.

Comment: Is there a way around this or am I out of luck?

Comment: Where are you getting that link from?

Comment: I am get the file name from the customer's database and I upload the images to AWS from their server.  So, a lot of this is automated and I would like to not have to change my code to handle this if I could change a setting in AWS to handle this problem.

Comment: The customer's database is probably wrong. If you had a file, say `a.JPG` in the database but on disk is actually `a.jpg` then the OS doesn't care, but it gets uploaded with a lower-case extension. You'll need to reconcile the database with the *actual* file names.